# Smooth Scroll with Arrows

Tags: jquery, anchor, smooth-scrolling

Right now I have smooth scrolling anchors using some jquery and an easing attribute. I want to be able to scroll as well to each section with the arrow keys. How can I achieve this?

HTML

```
<ul class="desktop">
     <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US </a></li>
     <li><a href="#branding">BRANDING &amp; IDENTITY</a></li>
     <li><a href="#sponsorship">CAUSE MARKETING</a></li>
     <li><a href="#promotion">EVENT MANAGEMENT</a></li>
</ul>   

<div class="main-container" id="aboutus"></div>
<div class="main-container2" id="branding"></div>
<div class="main-container3" id="sponsorship"></div>
<div class="main-container4" id="promotion"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
    /*
    if you don't want to use the easing effects:
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    */
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: A fiddle goes a long way in making it easy for others to help you.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T53fa/26/

It is a prototype, there'S a lot of amelioration to do, but the logic is here.

I save the number of page in a var and wich page you are on.

```
var lengthDiv = $('.desktop').find('li').length;
var current = 0;
```

Then i added 1 line in click function :

```
current = $anchor.parent().index();
```

This will change the current page number.

I made a function on keydown that preventDefault() just to prevent a little scroll before animation and then i insert this function :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){e.preventDefault()})
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key == 38 && current > 0){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current - 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }else if(key == 40 && current < lengthDiv){
        $('.desktop').children('li').eq(current + 1).children('a').trigger('click')
    }
})
```

I summary, it check wich key is pressed (well actually it up but you understand) and then simulate a click on the good page.

**REMEMBER**, it's a prototype that you need to work. I can tell you a bug already, when you scroll in the page, it doesn't change the `current` var, but i'm sure you can figure out a way to do it ;)

Comment: Don't hesitate if you need further help, just don't ask me to do your code ;)

Comment: How would you initiate active navigation other than .click when you are over each div

Comment: If you mean when pressing key, i would, instead of saving the current page, save all the div offset and check the scroll position.

Comment: Lastly for some reason this affects my contact form. I cannot type in my input fields. Does it have something to do with keycode?

Comment: Ahah yes, it is the `e.preventDefault()` in keydown function. Sorry for the lack of formatting, but try this : `$(document).keydown(function(e){if($(':focus').length <= 0)e.preventDefault()})`